# How do I make a button play sounds in a certain order using an array?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, audio

I'm coding in Objective-C for the iPhone and I am trying  create an array that plays a series of sounds. For example the first time I press the button I want it play sound **"0.wav"**, but the second time I want it to play **"1.wav"**, then **"2.wav"**, **"3.wav"**, etc. Then when I've played a total of 14 sounds (up to "13.wav") I want the loop to start over playing with 0.wav. I've looked around Google and the Apple development documentation for almost 4 days without much luck. So if someone could help me generate a code for this that would be greatly appreciated and if you wouldn't mind could you attempt to explain the code briefly so that I can learn what each part does.

Thank you, Joey

---

**EDIT**

Okay I've gotten the Array part down (thanks to Thomas) however neither of us are sure how to implement the soundID from the array to the action where I play the sound and how to play that sound. I used the format Thomas used for his array below if that helps you with your answer.

Thanks, Joey

Comment: Are you asking for help with how you would make a button access a new element of an array each time it's pressed, or how you would take a .wav file and play it?

Comment: Well I'm really trying to ask how to implement as in how to access a new element of the array and then play that new element all in one easy step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the array of your different sounds and a variable to hold the current index:

```
NSArray *sounds = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.wav", @"1.wav", nil]; // add all your files here
NSUInteger currentSound = 0;
```

Then, when you handle your button tapped event, go to the next sound, and play it. If it's at the end of your NSArray, go back to index 0:

```
currentSound++;
if (currentSound >= [sounds count]) {
    currentSound = 0;
}

// play the sound. Just call your own method here
[self playSoundWithFilename:[sounds objectAtIndex:currentSound]];
```

Comment: Where should I put each of those codes. I currently have the first one in "viewDidLoad" and the second one in my action I call when the button is pressed to play the sound. Which is a void. Should it be an IBAction? And do I need to declare anything in my header file or is it all pre-done in the frameworks.

Also how do I play the sound file using the result I got from the array? I'm not sure how to use the current value of the array as the file soundID.

Comment: viewDidLoad is probably fine for the first part.
Make sure to release the NSArray in dealloc.
Your action can return void, I think you basically need IBAction to tell Interface Builder that it's an action. I understand that IBAction is equivalent to void.
Not sure about playing the sound, I've got no experience with that.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. It definitely helped a lot, I'll ask around about playing the sound.